# Why isnt my code finding the correct cells and Identifying duplicates?

Tags: excel, vba

My code works in relation to finding the correct cells and inputting them in the correct place. But it is meant to be identifying duplicates and therefore not put duplicates in. But for some reason it wont work. Below is the code

[image]

```
       Dim cell As Range
    Dim SubTaskWs As Worksheet
    Set SubTaskWs = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sub tasks")

    Dim Lastrow1 As Long
    Lastrow1 = SubTaskWs.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim Lastrow2 As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    i = 0

    For Each cell In SubTaskWs.Range("H4:H" & Lastrow1) ' Find task owners in sub tasks sheet and then clear previous tasks within employee sheet
        For Each ws In Sheets
            If SubTaskWs.Cells(cell.Row, "H") = ws.Name And SubTaskWs.Cells(cell.Row, "B") <> ws.Cells(cell.Row, "A") Then
                Lastrow2 = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                copyFormattingAbove ws, "A" & Lastrow2
                ws.Range("A" & Lastrow2).value = SubTaskWs.Cells(cell.Row, 2)
                ws.Range("B" & Lastrow2).value = SubTaskWs.Cells(cell.Row, 3)
            End If
        Next ws
    Next cell
```

Comment: How do you expect any of us to be able to give you an answer? We can't see your data, there could be any number of things. There is nothing obviously wrong with your code, as far as I can see. Start with a simple example of one cell and step through your code to see what's going on.

Comment: I have a basic sample excel file but i cannot seem to workout how to add it

Comment: You can't upload files, but you can attach a screenshot.

Comment: Ive uploaded several screen shots of different sheets, hope its clear

Comment: The tabsheets may change which is why its important to automate the process as the tabsheets and task owners names will change often

Comment: Ive updated the code, it works but it doesnt recognise or take into account duplicates. Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following will achieve your expected results, using the Find method to see if the worksheet contains the specified Task Name, if not found, then adding it.

I've also updated some of the ranges to match the image attached to your question, `If SubTaskWs.Cells(cell.Row, "C") = ws.Name Then` as it seems like the Sheet name is actually in Column C (not in Column H), also changed to look for Column B (Task Name) against Column B in the respective Sheet, where you where looking for A against B...

```
Sub Process()
Dim cell As Range
Dim Lastrow1 As Long, Lastrow2 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SubTaskWs As Worksheet: Set SubTaskWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SubTasks")

Lastrow1 = SubTaskWs.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In SubTaskWs.Range("C2:C" & Lastrow1) ' Find task owners in sub tasks sheet and then clear previous tasks within employee sheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If SubTaskWs.Cells(cell.Row, "C") = ws.Name Then
            Set FoundTaksName = ws.Range("B:B").Find(What:=SubTaskWs.Cells(cell.Row, "B"), LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If FoundTaksName Is Nothing Then
            'not found, so add
                Lastrow2 = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                ws.Range("A" & Lastrow2).Value = SubTaskWs.Cells(cell.Row, "A")
                ws.Range("B" & Lastrow2).Value = SubTaskWs.Cells(cell.Row, "B")
            Else
            'found
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
Next cell
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to be able to list a number of Worksheet names in the cell, you can achieve that by using the InStr function to see if the worksheet name appear within the contents of that given cell and then progress accordingly, such as below:

```
Sub Process()
Dim cell As Range
Dim Lastrow1 As Long, Lastrow2 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SubTaskWs As Worksheet: Set SubTaskWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SubTasks")

Lastrow1 = SubTaskWs.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In SubTaskWs.Range("C2:C" & Lastrow1) ' Find task owners in sub tasks sheet and then clear previous tasks within employee sheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, SubTaskWs.Cells(cell.Row, "C"), ws.Name, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
            Set FoundTaksName = ws.Range("B:B").Find(What:=SubTaskWs.Cells(cell.Row, "B"), LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If FoundTaksName Is Nothing Then
            'not found, so add
                Lastrow2 = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                ws.Range("A" & Lastrow2).Value = SubTaskWs.Cells(cell.Row, "A")
                ws.Range("B" & Lastrow2).Value = SubTaskWs.Cells(cell.Row, "B")
            Else
            'found
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code but unfortunately it doesnt seem to do anything. When i run the macro it doesnt change anything

Comment: @LawrenceForster Please try it again, I've updated a number of things... Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks works great, works so much better than what i had before !!!!

Comment: @LawrenceForster please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks! :)

Comment: YEs i will do! One question, if the cell had say "AA, BB, CC" in, is there a way it can recognise each individual name and put the task on each of there sheets.

Comment: @LawrenceForster it is possible, I've now updated my answer to make that possible. :)